# Google Drive API v3 - complex query multiple file types

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to filter by multiple file types and get all of them by using the OR operator.
In the following example I'm trying to get PDF files and 3D model files (these are .OBJ files or .ZIP files which contain a .OBJ file inside them).

This is my Q parameter:

```
(mimeType = 'application/pdf') or ((mimeType = 'application/zip' or mimeType = 'application/octet-stream') and fullText contains '.obj')
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid",
        "message": "Invalid Value",
        "locationType": "parameter",
        "location": "q"
      }
    ],
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid Value"
  }
}
```

If I use either:

```
(mimeType = 'application/pdf')
```

or

```
((mimeType = 'application/zip' or mimeType = 'application/octet-stream') and fullText contains '.obj')
```

it works, but when I combine them with the OR operator, then it stops working. Any ideas why this might be happening?

I'm using the .NET client but I also tested it in the API reference and it does not work either.
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list

Comment: In java, I'm using something like this to get image and video `" 'root' in parents and trashed=false and mimeType contains 'video/' or mimeType contains 'image/' "`

Answer (score 3):

For some reason `fullText` didn't work here. Using `name` in place of `fullText` worked.

```
(mimeType = 'application/pdf') 
or 
((mimeType = 'application/zip' or mimeType = 'application/octet-stream') and name contains '.obj')
```

I guess it is better to use `name` to query by filenames.